# Applied for a UK visa as a couple, but only wife received a notification about getting her passport back. Should I be worried?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, application-status

My wife and I applied for UK tourist visas. We applied together, with me sponsoring both of us. Today, she received an email from TLS contact, subject 'Application Return by Courier' saying:

> Your passport and any returned supporting documents have now been sent
>   back to you by courier to the address you provided when you submitted
>   your application.

However, I have not received the same message to my email, even though we have previously gotten the same emails from them.

Would UKVI send only one package for group of applicants (we are at the same address), or would they be sent separately and I need to wait for mine to arrive?

Comment: Did you (or she) apply as the primary?

Comment: I am the main applicant. We applied via TLScontract.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using a third party service for your application?  Why not use the Visa4UK service offered by the UK Government?  TLSContact looks very very poor for a website (landing page says you are bound by the Terms and Condictions, Privacy Policy and Use of Cookies, but links to *none* of those things - which is basically illegal in the UK...)

Comment: That's fine. You will get a separate notification. Chill for a while.

Comment: Actually we have applied online at visa4uk. But we have to submit all of the documents to TLS contact. This is required by UKVI :(

Comment: @Moo it's the way things work with UKVI.  They use Visa4UK and print out the form and take it to the VFS.  It's just part of WHAT IS, and explained at the end of the Visa4UK application.

Comment: @GayotFow I dont understand where TLS comes in - it looks like a third party site (note: being British, I havent ever had to apply for a British visa...) and just looking at it would put me off from using it to apply for a British visa.  The official gov.uk site for Visa4UK doesnt mention it, and there is nothing on the TLS site (https://uk.tlscontact.com/) which offers any explanation as to the relationship between TLS and the UK Government...  should I ask this in a question?

Comment: @Moo you can certainly ask :) I will write an answer explaining that it is part of "WHAT IS" if that's of any use :)

Comment: My wife also received a message from DHL about the visa package being delivered. It seem like UKVI send to her only. Maybe mine will be late. Does anyone has the same problem and know the outcome?

Comment: You'll know the outcome when your packages arrive. For privacy reasons the UK **does not** say whether you were approved or refused by email. The message you received is exactly the same for both possibilities.

Comment: @Moo once you've filled out your online application at visa4uk, the site then instructs you to print the application, make an appointment at TLS, and take the application with you when you go to the appointment.  It would make a good question since it is certainly confusing for those looking for information about how the process works.

Comment: @Moo: "just looking at it would put me off from using it to apply for a British visa".  Surely you're aware that this is the point of the entire process.  Anyway, you don't have a choice in the matter.  http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64763/where-can-one-apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-a-proper-embassy

Comment: We received a separate notification and package from UKVI (even though we applied together).

Comment: @GayotFow - another bounty raised for you to answer

Comment: Please how long afterwards did your visa arrive after your wife's

Answer (score 6):

You and your wife applied for the UK Standard Visitor Visa and used UKVI's  commercial 3rd party to submit your applications.  You applied as the primary and your wife applied as a dependent.  Your wife got a notification email and you did not and this is creating stress for you.  So you have asked...

> Would UKVI send only one package for group of applicants (we are at
>   the same address), or would they be sent separately and I need to wait
>   for mine to arrive?

You need to wait for your notification to arrive.

One scenario is they may have decided that they want a different ECO to decide on each application.  This would especially be true if you or your wife have a history with them.  This can cause the decisions to be posted in a random order, and it's nothing to be concerned about.

Another likely scenario is that your evidence as the primary was sent to one of their Risk Assessment Units for analysis. The consulate got the word that the analysis was complete and emailed your wife, but could not email you because they were waiting for your stuff to return.

After your stuff was returned from the RAU (or any other of the analysis units they use), they emailed you.  This would have resulted in separate emails and separate bundles being returned to their commercial 3rd party now awaiting your pick up.

There are other scenarios where a primary's application can get separated, but this is the most likely.

> Should I be worried?

The "best practices" approach is to **avoid second guessing what is going on behind the scenes**.  There are lots of things that can cause these types of situations and there's no chance of guessing what is happening.  "*Post-submission Anxiety*", however, is common and there's no cure for it other than to brass it out.